# How to search for data and access it from cloud firestore with Flutter before being authenticated?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-web

In my application, I have two users, hospitals and patients. They are both being authenticated by firebase SDK therefore, a registered hospital is able to log in as a patient. I managed to register a patient with a username and it is being stored in firestore, however, I would like to search for that username in the DB before the person has logged in so that no other user such as a hospital can log in without that specific username. Thus, how do I search for that specific username and validate it before a person has even logged in?

Answer (score 0):

Use the **Firebase Admin SDK** to query the collection where the user name is stored (Admin SDK will bypass all the security rules, so you don't have to worry about the authentication).

If you have a backend server, then you can use the **firebase admin SDK** to query the firestore database for the username.

If you don't have a backend then you can use the **Firebase Cloud Functions** to do the same. (serverless)
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions